# What does JQuery $(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION) do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found the following code in a JavaScript object:

```
;(function(App, $, undefined){

    if (typeof App == 'undefined') window.App = {};


    App.SomeObject = { 

         MY_FUNCTION: 'myfunction',

         myfunction: function(element) {
                var self = App.SomeObject;
                if (element.getSize() < 1) {
                   // case 1
                } else {
                       // case 2
                }

        },

        secondFunction: function() {
            var self = App.SomeObject;
            $(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION);
        }

    }

})(App, jQuery);
```

In secondFunction I call

```
$(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION);
```

**What is this line actually doing?**

**When I call $(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION); from another function which arguments is myfunction called with?**

**Edit:** I copied this example from some other code but I did not get the meaning. I also see the following at some other part of the code:

```
myfunction(someElement);
$(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION);
```

I do not get what it means.

**Edit:** From the JQuery [trigger documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) I know that trigger will call the member function myfunction of SomeObject, but I do not know which parameters are being used. From my understanding the method will not work without any parameter because if (element.getSize() < 1) will give an error.

Comment: I have never seen `trigger()` used that way.  It is used to "trigger" an event.  like `$(document).trigger('click');` would trigger the click event.

Comment: Does that function return an event object?

Comment: @GaryStorey myfunction returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery trigger** use in 2 way:

**A) .trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )**

```
eventType
           Type: String
           A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as click or submit.

extraParameters
           Type: Array or PlainObject
           Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.
```

**B) .trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )**

```
event
          Type: Event
          A jQuery.Event object.

extraParameters
          Type: Array or PlainObject
          Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.
```

So you can fire and event by Trigger (**Native events [click, submit,...]** and **Custom events [designed by jQuery Codes]**)

### .

**Edited:**

In your case your are trying trigger one of document custom evens but **some parts of you codes are Incomplete**

You must assign your behavior to ducument first, then fire it with trigger.
I wrote a sample for you with explain each step **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xwuxhg60/1/)**

**Complete Code:**

```
;(function($){
    App=$;

    console.log("Step 1 >> The class of My Object is defining as SomeObject \r\n.")
    App.SomeObject = { 
         BehaviorName: 'TestBehavior',

         TestBehavior: function(target, myElement) {
             console.log("Step 6 >> TestBehavior is Running now...\r\n.");
             var self = App.SomeObject;
             if ($(myElement).width() < 100) {
                 console.log("Step 7 >> element.width ("+$(myElement).width()+") is less than 100px\r\n.");
             } else {
                 console.log("Step 7 >> element.width ("+$(myElement).width()+") is greater than 100px\r\n.");
             }
        },
        secondFunction: function(myElement) {
            console.log("Step 4 >> secondFunction is Running now...\r\n.");
            var self = App.SomeObject;
            console.log("Step 5 >> Firing one of document custom events by TRIGGER and this details:\r\n          EvenType  =  self.BehaviorName (='TestBehavior')    &   otherParameters  =  element\r\n.");
            $(document).trigger(self.BehaviorName,myElement);
        }
    }        
})(jQuery);

console.log("Step 2 >> Assining a new behavior to the page document with this detail:\r\n          eventType = BehaviorName value of SomeObject    &   Handler  =  TestBehavior of SomeObject\r\n.")
$(document).on($.SomeObject.BehaviorName,$.SomeObject.TestBehavior);
console.log("Step 3 >> Calling secondFunction of SomeObject\r\n.")
$.SomeObject.secondFunction($('#sampleElement'));
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Then your trigger can fire the assigned *custom event* to ducument, by using a EventType (as string) and extraParameters << using method A**

Comment: From the JQuery trigger documentation I know that trigger will call the member function myfunction, but I do not know which parameters are being used.

Comment: @confile, i changed my answer and explained all steps of your sample with a new one base your sample but with corrected codes. see this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well first off what is `self.MY_FUNCTION`? Looks like it's defined to be: `MY_FUNCTION: 'myfunction'`.

So what does `$(document).trigger('myfunction')` do? It triggers the custom `myfunction` event on the `$(document)` object.

That means for the trigger to do anything there should a be a listener somewhere in your code that looks like this:

```
$(document).on('myfunction', function() { 
    console.log('custom event triggered!');
});
```

Comment: myfunction is not defined without any arguments. This is why I am wondering how it works and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** API docs:

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements
>   for the given event type.

Your trigger is not linked to an event however. Perhaps you meant to do something like the following:

```
window.App = window.App || {};

window.App.SomeObject = {

    myFunction: function (event) {
        console.log('EVENT FIRED!');
        console.log(event);
    },

    init: function () {
        $(document).bind('myEvent', function (event) {
            window.App.SomeObject.myFunction(event);
        });
    }

}

$(function () {
    window.App.SomeObject.init();
});

$(document).trigger('myEvent');
```

You will want to `bind()` the event to a function.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ztjLLmvt/1/)

**UPDATE**

Your question is "What does JQuery $(document).trigger(self.MY_FUNCTION) do?"

The answer: Triggers an "event" called `'myFunction'`. Since nothing seems to be bound (via `bind()`) to the event `'myFunction'`, trigger does nothing. Moreover, your `secondFunction()` is never called anyway.

Comment: No I mean what I wrote. The code I find uses the trigger with a method call.

Comment: Did you read my question? What your answer is is a completely different thing.

Comment: Assume that secondFunction is called somewhere else.